# How to get allTags() in laravel from a filtered model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models Song and Album.

Song is Taggable(using eloquent-taggable).

1)Song belongs_to Album.

Album has columns name and language.

I want to get all tags of Song for a particular Album language.

I tried

```
Song::join('albums','albums.id','=','songs.album_id')
     ->where('albums.language', 'hindi')
     ->allTags()->orderBy('count', 'DESC')->get();
```

But not working.

Comment: Do you have a relationship set up in your Song model for album? Also, in the `orderBy` your referencing a `count` column, which table is this on?

Comment: Yes I have a relationship defined in model.`count` is referencing Tags table.I am getting error `allTags() is undefined for a query", but this is working `Song::allTags()->orderBy('count', 'DESC')->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allTags` is a static method that should be called on the model directly. When you start to add constraints or chain on relationship method to an `Eloquent` model an instance of `Builder` will be returned.

I would suggest, if you haven't already done so, to create a `Tag` model that extends `\Cviebrock\EloquentTaggable\Models\Tag` and then define a relationship for the songs. Your model will then look something like:

```
namespace App;

class Tag extends \Cviebrock\EloquentTaggable\Models\Tag
{
    /**
     * Songs Relationship.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
     */
    public function songs()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Song::class, 'taggable', 'taggable_taggables', 'tag_id', 'taggable_id');
    }
}
```

If you already have the model but don't have the relationship then simply add the above relationship to that model.

Then you should be able to get all of the Tags with:

```
 $tags = Tag::whereHas('songs.artist', function ($query) {
    $query->where('language', 'hindi');
})->orderBy('count', 'DESC')->get();
```

---

If you don't want to create a new model that you could do something like:

```
Song::with('tags')
    ->whereHas('artist', function ($query) {
        $query->where('language', 'hindi');
    })
    ->get()
    ->flatMap(function ($song) {
        return $song->tags;
    })
    ->unique()
    ->sortByDesc('count');
```

For more information on collection please have a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections)

Answer (score 1):

At first create relation on song and album as :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentTaggable\Taggable;

    class Song extends Model
    {
        use Taggable;
        protected $fillable = ['name','title','album_id'];
        public $timestamps = false;

        public function album() {
            return $this->belongsTo(Album::class, 'album_id');
        }
    }
```

and then make query as :

```
$songs = Song::with(['album','tags'])->whereHas('album', function($q) {
                    $q->where('language', '=', 'hindi');
                })->get();
```

This will returns you all songs which belongs to albums which has "hindi" language with their tags.